# Disable 'Mechanical click' right-click synaptic clickpad

Tags: thinkpad, synaptic, click-packages, click-policy

I'm having a hard time finding the answer to this, I think partially because I'm not sure what the correct term for 'Mechanical click' is. I'm referring to pressing on the clickpad until the actual pad mechanically clicks down, versus the touch pad sensing a finger tap.

When I do a 'hard click' or 'mechanical click', it is interpreted as a right-click. I'd like to disable this, and have it seen as a normal left-touch/left-click.

"synclicnt -l" does not show either the 'FastTaps' or 'FingerPress' properties.

Comment: Which version and flavor of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: What you refer to as “mechanical click” is called a clickpad's “SoftButton” functionality.

Comment: This may help you: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Touchpad/#ClickPad

Comment: @dessert Thanks for the comments. It's Ubuntu 17.04. Checking out the link!